# Postfix: How to reject mail to non-sender?

Tags: postfix

Does anyone know if there's a way to reject mail to recipients that aren't the sender? That is, sender can only send mail to him/herself. My take is that `local_recipient_maps` probably isn't designed for this.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: @gapsf AFAIK `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` determines if the recipient on its own satisfies certain conditions. In my case, each sender is only allowed to send mail to him/herself so the allowable recipient depends on who the sender is. Is `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` the right option for this? Or should each sender belong to a unique class?

Comment: Depends on whether you are solving an edge case, or want a *generic* solution for arbitrary senders. If the list of to-be-restricted senders is enumerable and short, you can use nested restriction classes. Otherwise, you have to extend postfix beyond its built-in map features, usually through policy, filter or milter interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postfix there is no simple configuration where you can say condition like "if recipient = sender". Also in general case there is more then one recipient in one mail can be. So what you suppose to do with such mail? Postfix cant "split" mail for each recipient and send it only to one of recipients. So you may want to rewrite (remove) all recipients from mail except sender but its nearly impossible in postfix at least. MTAs not suitible for such manipulations because its primary task - mail delivery not transforming mail.
https://high5.nl/mirrors/www.postfix.org/BUILTIN_FILTER_README.html#limitations

Also you should know about difference between recipients in smtp session and recipients in mail headers.
Real recipients are in smtp sessions (envelop), header is just a text and may have any sender/recipient or may not have it at all. So you cant rely on headers.

So with https://high5.nl/mirrors/www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions you can accept or reject on recipient value only using this format https://high5.nl/mirrors/www.postfix.org/access.5.html

In most postfix's checks you can check one value against some predefined value list. You cant get two values from different parts of smtp session or mail and compare them like in programming language.

So forget about smtpd restrictions.

Even with      https://high5.nl/mirrors/www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html you cant compare recipient and sender (or any two values).

I see only one (except writing milter) possibilty when you can compare sender and recipient https://high5.nl/mirrors/www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html

Write script for  `check_policy_service` to check if sender = recipient and configure smtpd to use it https://high5.nl/mirrors/www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html#client_config

Comment: The policy service actually is easy and convenient way to impose such limits. And it's quite easy to write.

Comment: I was use postfix at work long time ago and never use check_policy_service with my own script. And now i have no possibilty to check it.  Am i right about postfix checks limitations?